# Function that returns itself in R?

Tags: r, functional-programming

In Lambda calculus, Y -combinator returns itself like this **Y a = a Y a**, specifially [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003225/rosetta-stone-y-combinator). Suppose some trivial function such as **y(x)=2*x+1** (suppose Church numbers for the sake of simplicity) and I want to do it **Y y** to which I want some sort of break-out -function. I want to do something like this

1. calculate y(1) --->3
2. calculate y(3) --->7
3. calculate y(7) ...
4. ...
5. terminate on the n-th case

How can I do this in R using the functional way of thinking? Is there something built-in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really understand the notation of the lambda calculus, so can't know for sure what the Y-combinator is, but I wonder if the R function `Recall()` [(help page here)](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Recall.html) wouldn't help you build what you're after.  Here is an example of its use to calculate a factorial:

```
# Calculate 4!
(function(n) {if (n<=1) 1 else n*Recall(n-1)})(4)
```

And here it is applied to the example you described:

```
(function(x, n) {if (n<=1) x else Recall(2*x+1, n-1)})(x=1, n=1)
# [1] 1
(function(x, n) {if (n<=1) x else Recall(2*x+1, n-1)})(x=1, n=2)
# [1] 3
(function(x, n) {if (n<=1) x else Recall(2*x+1, n-1)})(x=1, n=3)
# [1] 7
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
myfun = function(x) { 2*x+1 }

N = 10; seed = 3; i = 1
for(i in 1:N){
     seed = Y = myfun(seed)
     print(Y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a function, `g`, that transforms a function `f` 
into `function(x) f(f(f(f(...f(x)))))` (n times, with n not known in advance),
the following should do.

```
compose_with_itself_n_times <- function(f,n) {
  function(x) {
    for(i in seq_len(n)) {
      x <- f(x)
    }
    x
  }
}
f <- function(x) 2*x+1
g <- compose_with_itself_n_times(f,10)
g(1)
```